# What is a crypt in a histopathological image?

Tags: cancer, histopathology

I am doing a science fair project on using histopathological images for cancer diagnosis, and I came across something that says a characteristic is exemplified by superficial serrated architecture and elongated crypts, I was wondering what that meant.

Comment: What tissue? Could you give more information on the sample, "cancer" is incredibly broad.

Answer (score 2):

You should give more details and information to this question as we don't know what tissue/cancer you're referring to.

If I'm just taking a guess I'd say you might mean [**intestinal glands**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/intestinal-gland) which form tube-like glands called **crypts** found in the lining of the gastrointestinal system (i.e., digestive tract). Cancerous tissue including the crypts can be colorectal carcinoma for example. Superficial serrated architecture most likely refers to sessile serrated polyps or colorectal serrated lesions.

- [Colorectal carcinoma: Pathologic aspects](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3418538/)
- [Superficially serrated adenoma: a proposal for a novel subtype of colorectal serrated lesion](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29789649/)
- [Sessile Serrated Polyps: Detection, Eradication, and Prevention of the Evil Twin](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4427517/)